# How to send date selected in DatePickerDialog to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I used a DatePickerDialog to get the selected date from user by clicking on a TextView. But the thing is how do I send that value(date) from the TextView to Firebase? Can the date be converted into string?

```
TextView startDate;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener startDateDateSetListener;


startDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(leaveForm.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                    startDateDateSetListener, year, month, day);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
            
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    startDateDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: dd/mm/yyy: " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);

            String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            startDate.setText(date);
        }
    };

private void applyLeave() {
    String leave_type = leaveType.getSelectedItem().toString(); //Spinner
    
    String start_date = startDate.getText().toString();

    leavedetails = new leaveDetails(leave_type, start_date);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    reference.child(userID).child("leaveRequest").push().setValue(leavedetails).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(leaveForm.this, "Leave Request Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(leaveForm.this, "Leave Request Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to use **String start_date = startDate.getText().toString();** , but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest storing it as a timestamp and then converting it back to a date and time when you need it.

This example gets you the date and time, but if you wanted to get midnight on that date then just leave the last three arguments as '0'.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(picker.getYear(), picker.getMonth(), picker.getDayOfMonth(), picker.getHours(), picker.getMinutes(), picker.getSeconds());
date = Long.toString(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

This will also ensure that you can easily convert it into any timezone you might need in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the response!. This will be useful for me if I want to retrieve time in the future. I decided to change my TextView to EditText and I was able to send it as a String.